# Three JS Camera control mouse + kbd

Tags: three.js

As the title suggests I want to move a camera in ThreeJS.
Im currently letting the camera move on mousedown making it circle a point at which it looks and I want to let keyboard controls move the camera in x and z, thus moving the point at which it looks as well as the position of the camera. The lookAt target is currently 0,0,0.

Having tried the `translateX`, and `translateZ` it would move the cameras position relative to its own tilt and angle. Thus, looking down, "forward" would bring the camera down in world Y-axis where I want to move it in world X and Z only.
Camera is perspective if it matters, and the scrollwheel sets radious of orbiting cirle.
Version is r55.

Here's the current code (mostly copied from examples) that doesnt move camera at all.

```
if (userMouse.isDown){
    theta = - ( ( userMouse.position.x - userMouse.down.position.x ) * userMouse.acceleration ) +  userMouse.down.theta;
    phi = ( ( userMouse.position.y - userMouse.down.position.y ) * userMouse.acceleration ) + userMouse.down.phi;
    phi = Math.min( 160, Math.max( 20, phi ) );
}

camera.position.x = userCam.radious * Math.sin( theta * Math.PI / 360 ) * Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
camera.position.y = userCam.radious * Math.sin( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
camera.position.z = userCam.radious * Math.cos( theta * Math.PI / 360 ) * Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 360 );
camera.lookAt(userCam.target);
camera.updateMatrix();
```

Ive looked through examples and scoured the Interwebs, but have not found this setup.
My guess is I would use some transformWorldMatrix or use the rotation of the camera to get the direction and then just add a movement value.

Im sure its not terribly tricky, I just cant wrap my head around it.
So; how would I move the camera in world X and Z with regard to where its looking?
Sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Check [OrbitControls](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html) and [TrackballControls](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html) examples code, maybe will be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but neither gives me a hint how to do this. Or maybe they do but Im too thick to get it.